# ASP.NET Cache and Web Farm Solutions

Tags: asp.net, caching, web-farm

What are the solutions to get cache to work with a web farm in an ASP.NET MVC site?  I know there are third party caching providers (NCache), but is there a simpler way without purchasing extra services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up Memcached ( Memcached.org) (which is distributed cache solution used at lots and lots of sites.

Comment: Can this be installed on just one of the web farm servers? All of them, or a separate server.?